# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard (SQL Server Express)

Tags: csv, import, sql-server-express

So I am having a heck of a time importing a CSV file. The ultimate goal is to create a repeatable process to import the file. The only way I've been able to import the file is in a roundabout way using MS Access (Import into Access then export to SQL Server), which it happily and merrily does without issue.

But surely SQL Server (Express or otherwise) should be able to import it also.

The file is out in the wild here: http://ourairports.com/data/ and specifically: http://ourairports.com/data/airports.csv

It is a great data set to play with (real world data) and I have designs on normalizing it, bringing it into SSRS and what not, largely to learn and have something to 'show' a prospective employer.

But I'll be damned if the file will import without errors. Ideally the columns will import and convert appropriately, i.e. columns that are numeric should end up in the table defined as Int or whatever is most appropriate.

The most frequent error I am seeing is:

```
Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "wikipedia_link" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page."
```

Ideally I'd like to import the file via T-SQL and Bulk Insert, but have similar issues.

Perhaps if someone can take a gander and see what's up, ideally I'd learn something here and not looking for just a quick answer, unless of course I'm just doing something stupid like forgetting a check box.

Thanks

Comment: Gah! Having no luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, Took me a while to figure out what was going on here!

Basically, it passes the validation step because SQL looks at the mappings and compares the datatypes of the columns in the table with the first few rows of the csv. (Top 8 rows I believe.)

In this case, the top 8 rows are all blank! Meaning SQL doesn't have a problem because there's no data to check.

Then, you go to import and SQL hits the first row with a link (Row 41), this then breaks the validation.

Unfortunately, you can't go changing the datatypes of the columns and expecting that to work, because, well, it doesn't. (Thank You Microsoft!)

One solution here is to get one (ideally all) of the rows with Wiki Links, to the top of the spreadsheet and re-import.

**EDIT**

Ahha! A real solution! There's a registry key change that sets the amount of rows excel validates. Changing this to zero makes the checker look through the top 16,000 rows.

You need to change the following registry key to zero:

```
32 Bit Machine:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows

64 Bit Machine:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. The file does indeed open in Excel "as is" downloaded from the website. MS Access also seems to happily enough  import it and export it successfully to SQL Server.

SQL Server itself does not however want to import it as is, and sorting the csv prior to importing only changes the row at which the unrecoverable error occurs at.

Comment: I would ultimately look to a code only solution so as to create a repeatable process, using in part Bulk Import (T-SQL).

Comment: I did yes, and with no change. Not sure how changing those keys would effect how SQL Server imports the CSV. The goal is to import directly into SQL Server. That CSV files are associated with Excel is incidental.

Comment: `Bulk Insert airports from 'C:\development\airports.csv'
With (
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
`